# How do I change the YouTube player on my web site

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, media-player

How do I change the YouTube player on my web site. Like http://vidsshare.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for the embed video. The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript.

Using the API's JavaScript functions, you can queue videos for playback; play, pause, or stop those videos; adjust the player volume; or retrieve information about the video being played. You can also add event listeners that will execute in response to certain player events, such as a player state change or a video playback quality change

Just check the link above to know more about it.

For more information, check this [YouTube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo). This demo demonstrates the YouTube Player API's functions. Embedded players must have a viewport that is at least 200px by 200px. If the player displays controls, it must be large enough to fully display the controls without shrinking the viewport below the minimum size.